# EWS getting phone number from directory folder

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm querying EWS with `DistinguishedFolderId` set to Directory. If I add

```
<t:FieldURI FieldURI="persona:PhoneNumber" />
```

to the field URIs I don't get the phone number returned. Also if I try to expand the BaseShape to AllProperties I get a failure.

```
<soap:Body>
    <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
      <m:ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
        <t:AdditionalProperties>
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="persona:DisplayName" />
        </t:AdditionalProperties>
      </m:ItemShape>
      <m:IndexedPageItemView MaxEntriesReturned="100" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" />
      <m:ParentFolderIds>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="directory" />
      </m:ParentFolderIds>
    </m:FindItem>
  </soap:Body>
```

What I'm trying to do is construct a query which will return me the person (not the contact, I need to look into the directory not the contacts) details with the phone number from the tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - found the answer to this one. `FindPeople` and `FindItems` aren't going to return the phone number by default, that's some kind of extension.

See [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/56a652c3-13e4-4e24-8c84-e6c40d1635e8/cannot-fetch-additional-properties-when-using-findpeople?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5d74cb02-c10f-4e3d-9b48-cd83faf37423/getting-phone-numbers-using-findpeople-in-ews?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment) where it was partially answered on msdn forums. The solution proposal is to use the `GetPersona` method and query each PersonId individually.